# Awk help required

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk

I wrote the below script to check expiry age of users on psql

```
#!/bin/bash 
  echo "" 
  echo "Performing User Expiry Check" 
  echo ""
  CONTAINER_ID=$(docker ps -a | grep -i "postgresql" | awk '{print $1}')
  sudo docker exec -i $CONTAINER_ID psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U dbuser
-c "select u.email, now() - to_timestamp(c.created_date/1000)::date password_age from credential c join user_entity u on u.id=c.user_id where now() - to_timestamp (c.created_date/1000)::date > interval '0 days' and c.type='password'" | grep -v "-" | grep -A 5000 -v "email" | grep -v "rows"
```

This is the result when I run the script:

```
root@eserver-app-04:/home/dbuserr# ./testkc.sh

Performing  User Expiry Check

admin@linux.ai | 16 days 12:59:19.519782
support@linux.ai | 16 days 12:59:19.519782

root@eserver-app-04:/home/dbuserr#
```

The below is working fine:

```
| awk '{ if ($3+0>60) { print "Major - User Expires in 30 days" } else { print "No Users set to Expire" } } ' >> /home/dbuser/userexpire.txt
```

I get this output written to the file

```
No Users set to Expire.
```

My Question is: How do I add another 2 statements to awk?

I have:

```
| awk '{ if ($3+0>60) { print "Major - User Expires in 30 days" }
```

I would like to add:

```
if ($3+0>80) { print "Critical - User Expires in 10 days" }
```

and

```
if ($3+0<60) { print "Notice - No Users set to Expire" }
```

How do i add them all together is the below correct?

```
| awk '{ if ($3+0>60) { print "Major - User Expires in 30 days" } {
elif ($3+0>80) { print "Critical - User Expires in 10 days" } elif
($3+0<60) { print "Notice - No Users set to Expire" } } ' } ' >>
/home/dbuser/userexpire.txt
```

Comment: You already have a script to extract the data, write another one that reads the results and do the other steps.  You *could* try to integrate it all in 1 script, but it would be faster to just wrap it up in another script IMHO.

Comment: please update the question to include data above/below 80; also add the expected output

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks everyone, i have updated the main question.

Comment: What about the case where `$3+0 == 60`? Also, writing `if (x>60) then y; else if (x>80) then z` means `z` is unreachable since if x is >80 then x is also >60 so that's not the logic you should be asking to have implemented.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to put all the commands of your script on the command line. You can put them in a file.

Put this all in a file called "userexpire.awk"

```
{
    if ($3+0>60) {
        print "Major - User Expires in 30 days"
    }
    else if ($3+0>80) {
        print "Critical - User Expires in 10 days"
    }
    else if ($3+0<60) {
        print "Notice - No Users set to Expire"
    }
}
```

And then execute it by doing

```
... whatever ... | awk -f userexpire.awk
```

The "-f userexpire.awk" tells awk to look in that file for the script instead of the command line.

This makes things much easier to write, test and debug.

Comment: I know its what the OP asked for but it has a couple of issues - 1) it'll never print `Critical - User Expires in 10 days` as the first 2 conditions are in the wrong order to allow that and 2) it won't print `Notice - No Users set to Expire` if $3 is exactly 60, that finale `else if ...` should just be `else` to allow that. The logic should be `if ($3>80) critical, else if ($3>60) major; else Notice`

Comment: Sure, I wasn't addressing the logic. I was just showing OP how to work with more complex code.

Comment: you can simplify the code : [ $3+0<60 ]  can be made into [ +$3 < 60 ] — simply having a plus sign [ + ] immediately to left of field/variable, with no space in between, is same as adding zero to it.

Answer (score 0):

Definitively made it too complicated :

```
mawk/gawk 'BEGIN {
    split((_=    "Notice - No Users set to Expire=")(_)(\
                  "Major - User Expires in 30 days="\
               "Critical - User Expires in 10 days"),___,"[=]+")
        ____ = (__=index(___[+_]=_,"t")) * (__+__—-)+__++

} $++NF=___[int((-(/[1-9][0][ \t]+days/)+$__)/____)]'


                  Notice  -   No    Users            set       to  Expire=
admin@linux.ai    |       1   days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
support@linux.ai  |       1   days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
admin@linux.ai    |       2   days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
support@linux.ai  |       2   days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
admin@linux.ai    |       3   days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
support@linux.ai  |       3   days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
admin@linux.ai    |       4   days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
support@linux.ai  |       4   days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
admin@linux.ai    |       5   days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
support@linux.ai  |       5   days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
admin@linux.ai    |       6   days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
support@linux.ai  |       6   days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
admin@linux.ai    |       7   days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
support@linux.ai  |       7   days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
admin@linux.ai    |       8   days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
support@linux.ai  |       8   days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
admin@linux.ai    |       9   days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
support@linux.ai  |       9   days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
admin@linux.ai    |       10  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
support@linux.ai  |       10  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
admin@linux.ai    |       11  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
support@linux.ai  |       11  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
admin@linux.ai    |       12  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
support@linux.ai  |       12  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
admin@linux.ai    |       13  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
support@linux.ai  |       13  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
admin@linux.ai    |       14  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
support@linux.ai  |       14  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
admin@linux.ai    |       15  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
support@linux.ai  |       15  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
admin@linux.ai    |       16  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
support@linux.ai  |       16  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
admin@linux.ai    |       17  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
support@linux.ai  |       17  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
admin@linux.ai    |       18  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
support@linux.ai  |       18  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
admin@linux.ai    |       19  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
support@linux.ai  |       19  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
admin@linux.ai    |       20  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
support@linux.ai  |       20  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire=
admin@linux.ai    |       21  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       21  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       22  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       22  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       23  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       23  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       24  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       24  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       25  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       25  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       26  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       26  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       27  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       27  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       28  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       28  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       29  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       29  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       30  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       30  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       31  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       31  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       32  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       32  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       33  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       33  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       34  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       34  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       35  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       35  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       36  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       36  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       37  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       37  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       38  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       38  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       39  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       39  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       40  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       40  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       41  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       41  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       42  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       42  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       43  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       43  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       44  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       44  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       45  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       45  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       46  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       46  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       47  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       47  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       48  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       48  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       49  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       49  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       50  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       50  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       51  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       51  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       52  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       52  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       53  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       53  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       54  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       54  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       55  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       55  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       56  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       56  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       57  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       57  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       58  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       58  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       59  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       59  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
admin@linux.ai    |       60  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire
support@linux.ai  |       60  days  12:59:19.519782  Notice    -   No       Users    set  to  Expire

admin@linux.ai    |       61  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
support@linux.ai  |       61  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
admin@linux.ai    |       62  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
support@linux.ai  |       62  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
admin@linux.ai    |       63  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
support@linux.ai  |       63  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
admin@linux.ai    |       64  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
support@linux.ai  |       64  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
admin@linux.ai    |       65  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
support@linux.ai  |       65  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
admin@linux.ai    |       66  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
support@linux.ai  |       66  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
admin@linux.ai    |       67  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
support@linux.ai  |       67  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
admin@linux.ai    |       68  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
support@linux.ai  |       68  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
admin@linux.ai    |       69  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
support@linux.ai  |       69  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
admin@linux.ai    |       70  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
support@linux.ai  |       70  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
admin@linux.ai    |       71  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
support@linux.ai  |       71  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
admin@linux.ai    |       72  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
support@linux.ai  |       72  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
admin@linux.ai    |       73  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
support@linux.ai  |       73  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
admin@linux.ai    |       74  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
support@linux.ai  |       74  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
admin@linux.ai    |       75  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
support@linux.ai  |       75  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
admin@linux.ai    |       76  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
support@linux.ai  |       76  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
admin@linux.ai    |       77  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
support@linux.ai  |       77  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
admin@linux.ai    |       78  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
support@linux.ai  |       78  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
admin@linux.ai    |       79  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
support@linux.ai  |       79  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
admin@linux.ai    |       80  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days
support@linux.ai  |       80  days  12:59:19.519782  Major     -   User     Expires  in   30  days

admin@linux.ai    |       81  days  12:59:19.519782  Critical  -   User     Expires  in   10  days
support@linux.ai  |       81  days  12:59:19.519782  Critical  -   User     Expires  in   10  days
admin@linux.ai    |       82  days  12:59:19.519782  Critical  -   User     Expires  in   10  days
support@linux.ai  |       82  days  12:59:19.519782  Critical  -   User     Expires  in   10  days
admin@linux.ai    |       83  days  12:59:19.519782  Critical  -   User     Expires  in   10  days
support@linux.ai  |       83  days  12:59:19.519782  Critical  -   User     Expires  in   10  days
admin@linux.ai    |       84  days  12:59:19.519782  Critical  -   User     Expires  in   10  days
support@linux.ai  |       84  days  12:59:19.519782  Critical  -   User     Expires  in   10  days
admin@linux.ai    |       85  days  12:59:19.519782  Critical  -   User     Expires  in   10  days
support@linux.ai  |       85  days  12:59:19.519782  Critical  -   User     Expires  in   10  days
admin@linux.ai    |       86  days  12:59:19.519782  Critical  -   User     Expires  in   10  days
support@linux.ai  |       86  days  12:59:19.519782  Critical  -   User     Expires  in   10  days
admin@linux.ai    |       87  days  12:59:19.519782  Critical  -   User     Expires  in   10  days
support@linux.ai  |       87  days  12:59:19.519782  Critical  -   User     Expires  in   10  days
admin@linux.ai    |       88  days  12:59:19.519782  Critical  -   User     Expires  in   10  days
support@linux.ai  |       88  days  12:59:19.519782  Critical  -   User     Expires  in   10  days
```